# Why Wireshark is not displaying RTPS sub-messages in the 'Info' column?

Tags: udp, wireshark, rtp, wireshark-dissector, data-distribution-service

I want to analyze the RTPS traffic in Wireshark.

I am running two applications that are transmitting and receiving a DDS (Data Distribution Service) topic in the same computer.

I can only see INFO_TS,DATA(p) in the info column and not the other sub-messages like HEARTBEAT, ACKNACK etc.,

Note: I tried using both shared memory and UDP4 protocol.

I have enabled RTPS dissection in the preferences Tab and expected to see RTPS sub-messages, but couldn't.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmucs.png)

Answer (score 0):

The submessages you mentioned *should* show up as illustrated in the Wireshark screenshot attached below.

Keep in mind that `HEARTBEAT` and `ACKNACK` submessages are only sent when doing reliable communications. Looking at the screenshot that you added, it only shows Participant discovery traffic. The associated submessages are marked as `DATA(p)`. In order for reliable communications to happen, Endpoint discovery must have kicked in first. This means that DataWriters and DataReaders are discovering each other and start to exchange reliable communications, if configured to do so. Your capture does not show your system arriving at that stage.

[image: Wireshark screenshot showing HEARTBEAT and ACKNACK submessages]

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your reply. I tried running two applications in two different computers ( connected over same WiFi)and after disabling the firewalls in both the computers Iam able to see the RTPS sub-messages like HEARTBEAT, ACKNACK. I don’t know why I can’t see those when I am running both applications within a single computer.

Comment: When you run both applications on the same computer, they are probably communicating over shared memory. Wireshark will not be able to intercept that. Another possibility is that you are communicating over loopback which is typically not intercepted by Wireshark on Windows. Participant discovery traffic will still be sent out to the network, probably a multicast address, which is why you were able to observe that. In order to provide a more detailed answer, more details are required about what DDS implementation you are using and how it has been configured.